# What nomenclature would contemporary descriptive grammar use to describe an "afterthought" lacking an explicit verb at the end of a sentence?

Tags: syntax, subordinate-clauses

> Jack has a lot of money—more than he needs.

How would contemporary descriptive grammar analyze **more than he needs** there?

Would "more than he needs" be analyzed as a supplemental noun phrase?

Or as a subordinate clause?

> ... (which is) more money than he needs

Or is it a restatement using the subject and verb of the main clause implicitly?

> <sup>Jack has</sup> more money than he needs.

Comment: An ascriptive NP supplement.

Comment: There is not one instance of that that I can find with google. It is a truncation of: John has a lot of money **which is** more than he needs. The em dash stands in for which is.

Comment: @Lambie:  The em-dash indicates that **more than he needs** is not integral to the main clause. It adds info.

Comment: You'd likely get a much fuller answer on EL&U

Comment: @gotube A much fuller answer? It's a very simple question: "more than he needs" is a noun phrase.Since it's set apart from the rest of the clause, it can only be a supplement (a kind of appendage). It adds information about "a lot of money" and hence is ascriptive rather than specifying.

Comment: which is more than he needs OR —more than he needs. mean the same thing.